# How to drive space separated values file with shelve

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a huge file containing space separated values formated as follows:

```
key1 0.553 1.45 0.666
key2 2.66 1.77 0.001
...
```

I would like to drive this file as a dictionary by using Shelve (or any other best-fitted module you suggest). In such a way I can query the first column as the key and the result to be all following values as a list, i.e.

```
In [1]: with shelve.open("file") as db:
   ...:    print db["key2"]
   ...:
Out [1]: [2.66, 1.77, 0.001]
```

Thank you very much for your suport.

Comment: `shelve` uses a binary structure (`pickle`). It is relatively trivial to read the file in using `csv` and convert to a `shelve` db or just hold it in memory.

Comment: Thanks @AChampion Holding in memory is not an option. Converting is, there is another choise bypassing convertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... possible method to efficientize the retrieval of items near to the end of the file?

1. Add a `offset` argument.
   This could be automated, if you implement the logic into `class DictFloatReader`.

   ```
   def __getitem__(self, item):
       offset = 0
       if isinstance(item, tuple):
           offset = item[1]
           item = item[0]

       self.fh.seek(offset)
   # Usage
   print(db["key2", 300*1024])
   ```
2. If your `keys` are **presorted**, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4 or a, b, c, you can use a `btree` search. This results in nearly the same **search time** for every `key`.
3. Switch to a **real** Database Fileformat which offers **indexing** and **random access**.
4. Hold it in **memory**, but you stated allready:
   *"Holding in memory is not an option"*

---

This will do what you want, for instance:

```
class DictFloatReader(object):
    def __init__(self, fpath):
        self.fpath = fpath
        self.fh = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.fh = open(self.fpath)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.fh.close()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        self.fh.seek(0)
        for line in self.fh:
            if line.startswith(item):
                return [float(f) for f in line[:-1].split(' ')[1:]]
```

> **Usage**

```
with DictFloatReader('file') as db:
    print(db["key2"])
    print(db["key1"])
    print(db["key2"])
```

> **Output**
>   [2.66, 1.77, 0.001]
>   [0.553, 1.45, 0.666]
>   [2.66, 1.77, 0.001]

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Comment: Excuse me @stovfl, can you suggest me possible method to efficientize the retrieval of items near to the end of the file? my actual file contains 400K lines and retrieving the items near to the end is very slow.

Comment: Thank you for the last editing @stovfl, it is very informative.